# Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, puppeteer, chrome-aws-lambda

I was trying to run Puppeteer on an AWS Lambda function and got the following error.

```
Error: Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser'
```

This has happened on both locally and when I deploy it to AWS as well.

The code:

```js
const chromium = require("chrome-aws-lambda");

const generateImg = async (reviewId) => {
  let browser = null;
  let result = null;

  try {
    const executablePath = await chromium.executablePath;
    browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      executablePath: executablePath,
      headless: chromium.headless,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(
      "https://www.example.com"
    );

    result = await page.screenshot();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "node-fetch": "2.7.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^21.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "sls offline --stage local"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: Which node version do you run with?

Comment: Why do you need to define puppeteer-core in package.json? The version required by chrome-aws-lambda is 10.x. Specifying 21.x may cause the conflict.

Comment: https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/issues/154 in case it helps

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. It happened due to a version conflict between `chrome-aws-lambda` and `puppeteer-core`

Comment: @Harshana and how did you fixed?

Comment: You have to use same versions of libraries for both `chrome-aws-lambda` and `puppeteer-core` .